# Strange message box layout on japanese display language

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have the next c# code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

and it works fine when windows display language is set to English.
The result is
[English message box](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5faxbggl5yshh8/english.png)

However when windows display language is changed to Japanese(Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Change display language) this message box is corrupted
[Japanese message box](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tvzwwnaea4vzv7/japanese.png)

What is the root cause of this issue? How to fix or workaround it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, Windows system locale has to be changed:

1.Open the Control Panel (icons view) in Windows 7 or Windows 8, and click/tap on the Region and Language (Windows 7) or Region (Windows 8) icon.
2. Click/tap on the Administrative tab, then click/tap on the Change system locale button.
3.Select which language to use when displaying text in programs that do not support Unicode, and click/tap on OK.
4.Click/tap on OK.